# Single instance of an object per transaction

Tags: spring, web-services, rest, jakarta-ee, cxf

I have a use case, that theoretically seems to me as it would be a solved problem. But i'm not able to find a sure fired implementation.

1. I've created a RESTful API, using Apache CXF, Spring and Hibernate
2. This application encompasses a standard Service-Proxy-DAO layered structure
3. I need to instantiate a custom logger object at my service (or pre-service) layer and initialize a bunch of parameters which will remain constant, for the most part through every call that goes through my application layers and back.
4. How can i, for every individual service call, initialize this logger object once, and use it across all my layers without having to instantiate it everytime. Either i inject the initialized object in every class i need or something on those lines.
5. I don't want to use static blocks, or pass the object in method signatures.

Is there anything that i can use as a part of the Spring, CXF or other java framework that allows me to implement this use-case.

EDIT: I would define a transaction as a single call to a web service endpoint, from invocation to response.

Comment: Have you ever heard of AOP ? If not, read this http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html and you'll be on your way - but it will probably take a while to get everything right.

Answer (score 4):

ThreadLocal would be an ideal candidate to solve your problem.

UPDATE:

Creating a thread local that is available in all the places where this "shared" reference is required will give all these contexts access to this resource without having to pass the reference around.

see http://www.appneta.com/blog/introduction-to-javas-threadlocal-storage/ - looks like a good explanation of how to use thread local and also deals with your problem space.

Comment: You probably want to expand your answer